# how do you disconnect an active user logged in to a box?

Tags: remote-desktop

how do you disconnect an active user logged in to a box? There should be a command line tool that comes with Windows, but I forgot it's name. It lists all the users logged in to a box and you can force disconnect of some, because, for example, you want to Remote Desktop to it and there's too many users.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tsdiscon.exe to disconnect a terminal services session or logoff.exe to terminate the session.

> **tsdiscon.exe** disconnects a session from a
>   terminal server. You must have Full
>   Control permission to disconnect
>   another user from a session.
>
> If no session ID or session name is
>   specified, tsdiscon disconnects the
>   current session. The console session
>   cannot be disconnected.
>
> Any applications that were running
>   when you disconnected the session are
>   automatically running when you
>   reconnect to that session with no loss
>   of data.
>
> **logoff.exe** Logs off a user from a session and
>   deletes the session from the server.
>   You can always log off from the
>   session to which you are currently
>   logged on. You must, however, have
>   Full Control permission to log off
>   users from other sessions.
>
> Logging off a user from a session
>   without warning can result in loss of
>   data at the user’s session. You should
>   send a message to the user using the
>   msg command to warn the user before
>   taking this action.
>
> If no ID or name for the session is
>   specified, logoff logs off the user
>   from the current session. If you
>   specify a session name, it must be an
>   active one.
>
> When you log off a user, all processes
>   end and the session is deleted from
>   the server.
>
> You cannot log off a user from the
>   console session.

Details are here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776289(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Terminal Services Administrator, installed as part of the windows admin pack. If it's installed and in your path, just running `tsadmin` will give you the ability to see who is logged in and you can disconnect/logoff/reset their sessions.